# Curious about ubuntu holding back packages during updates 22.04

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates, held-packages

After jumping around distros and learning a bit, I've finally settled back in with ubuntu, and I'm very happy with it. I understand every so often you run into little quirks with different distros.

I installed 22.04 when it was first released, and the first thing I did was remove snaps and replace them with flatpaks. I only say this because, to my knowledge, this is the only possibly "weird" thing I have done to the os.

With that said, I've noticed for a couple months or so now, when I apt update, 7/10 times it says that it's holding back packages. When this first started I got worried, thinking that the os was breaking. I looked around in forums and found options such as apt full upgrade, manually copy/paste held back packages then apt install said packages, and other workarounds that only work in terminal. I read that it's doing this because it wants/needs a new package for said updating package, and by apt installing it will go out and find extra dependencies for these packages. For some reason it wont know to do that automatically I guess? idk

I guess to get to the meat and potatoes of my question, is this normal with ubuntu these days? I've happily just dealt with it so far because I enjoy the os. But wish I could find a fix without having to jump through the extra hoop of manually intervening almost every update. I've been thinking of doing a clean install, thinking that might fix this quirk, but that feels extreme. Or just live with it and hope when the next LTS comes around that it will fix this. Or that after manually intervening so many times that it will eventually fix itself.

What do others think, Is there a fix I haven't found yet, is this just something special with ubuntu, just keep manually intervening and it'll fix itself one day so just live with it, hopefully new releases will fix it, do a clean install...?

Also is it a bad thing that I am installing these held back packages!?

Thanks for taking the time to read this, if there is a post of a fix or solution that I missed please let me know. Also I still consider myself new to linux, so you may have to add some extra explanation or context to any special terms or solutions.

Thank you

Comment: There's a reason for phased updates: Testing on a small pool before making them available for everybody.

Comment: Search this site for "phased updates". Your question will likely be closed as a duplicate of one of the search results.

Comment: "phased updates" don't know what that is. Thank you ill give it a look!

Comment: Wait. So if i have been forcing the phased updates to install should I do a clean install of the OS? Nothing seems to be broken. But it's like running sid in debian right? Is it sufficient enough to just stop forcing the updates?

Comment: It is OK to force the updates, you have not broken anything.  The only risk is that you will install a package that turns out to have issues. This is the exact same risk that everyone took for years before they started with the phased updates.

Answer (score 1):

When packages are held back, I found a solution by installing `aptitude` and then running "sudo aptitude safe-upgrade". Works for me, hope this helps :)